# How to split a string into an array in bash

Tags: bash, string, split

I have a problem with the output of a program. I need to launch a command in bash and take its output (a string) and split it to add new lines in certain places. The string looks like this:

```
battery.charge: 90 battery.charge.low: 30 battery.runtime: 3690 battery.voltage: 230.0 device.mfr: MGE UPS SYSTEMS device.model: Pulsar Evolution 500
```

basically it is an *xxx.yy.zz:* value, but the value may contain spaces.
Here's the output I'd like to get

```
battery.charge: 90
battery.charge.low: 30
battery.runtime: 3690
battery.voltage: 230.0
device.mfr: MGE UPS SYSTEMS
device.model: Pulsar Evolution 500
```

I have an idea to search for first dot and then look back from that position for space to put a new line there, but I'm not sure how to achieve it in Bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure bash solution, no external tools used to process the strings, just parameter expansion:

```
#! /bin/bash
str='battery.charge: 90 battery.charge.low: 30 battery.runtime: 3690 battery.voltage: 230.0 device.mfr: MGE UPS SYSTEMS device.model: Pulsar Evolution 500'

IFS=: read -a fields <<< "$str"

for (( i=0 ; i < ${#fields[@]} ; i++ )) ; do
    f=${fields[i]}

    notfirst=$(( i>0 ))
    last=$(( i+1 == ${#fields[@]} ))

    (( notfirst )) && echo -n ${f% *}

    start=('' $'\n' ' ')
    colon=('' ': ')
    echo -n "${start[notfirst + last]}${f##* }${colon[!last]}"
done
echo
```

Explanation: `$notfirst` and `$last` are booleans. The part before the last space `${f% *}` isn't printed for the first field, as there is no such thing. `$start` and `$colon` hold various strings that separate the fields: at the first item, `notfirst + last` is 0, so nothing is prepended, for the rest of the lines, `$notfirst` is 1, so a newline is printed, and for the last line, the addition gives 2, so a space is printed. Then, the part after the last space is printed `${f##* }`. Colon is printed for all lines except the last one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I'll use your solution although I understand almost nothing. Can I ask you for some additions? Because original string begin with STRING: " and end with ". I forgot to mention that I need to remove them. It's constant 9 characters on the beginning and one char. from the end of the string.

Comment: @user67524: Read about *Parameter Expansion* in `man bash`. To remove the parts, use `str=${str#STRING: "}; str=${str%"}`.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU sed, you can match each contiguous string (i.e. without whitespace) terminated by `:` and then place a newline before all but the first one:

```
sed 's/[^[:space:]]\+:/\n&/g2'
```

If your version of sed does not support the `gn` extension, you can use a plain `g` modifier

```
sed 's/[^[:space:]]\{1,\}:/\
&/g'
```

which will work the same except for printing an additional newline before the first key. You could use `perl -pe 's/\S+:/\n$&/g'` with the same proviso (there may be a perl equivalent of the GNU sed `g2` but I don't know it).

Comment: While you're at using GNU `sed`, you could also make it: `sed -r 's/\S+:/\n&/g2'`

Answer (score 3):

A `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -pe 's{\S+:}{$seen++ ? "\n$&" : "$&"}ge' file
battery.charge: 90 
battery.charge.low: 30 
battery.runtime: 3690 
battery.voltage: 230.0 
device.mfr: MGE UPS SYSTEMS 
device.model: Pulsar Evolution 500
```

**Explanation**

- `\S+:` matches string end with `:`.
- With all matched strings, we insert the newline before them `("\n$&")` except the first one `($seen++)`.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier using a tool that supports lookarounds:

```
$ s="battery.charge: 90 battery.charge.low: 30 battery.runtime: 3690 battery.voltage: 230.0 device.mfr: MGE UPS SYSTEMS device.model: Pulsar Evolution 500"
$ grep -oP '\S+:\s+.*?(?=\s+\S+:|$)' <<< "$s"
battery.charge: 90
battery.charge.low: 30
battery.runtime: 3690
battery.voltage: 230.0
device.mfr: MGE UPS SYSTEMS
device.model: Pulsar Evolution 500
```

If you wanted the result in an array:

```
$ IFS=$'\n' foo=($(grep -oP '\S+:\s+.*?(?=\s+\S+:|$)' <<< "$s"))
$ for i in "${!foo[@]}"; do echo "$i<==>${foo[i]}"; done
0<==>battery.charge: 90
1<==>battery.charge.low: 30
2<==>battery.runtime: 3690
3<==>battery.voltage: 230.0
4<==>device.mfr: MGE UPS SYSTEMS
5<==>device.model: Pulsar Evolution 500
```

---

EDIT: Explanation of the regex:

```
'\S+:\s+.*?(?=\s+\S+:|$)'
```

- `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters
- `:` matches `:`
- `\s+` matches one or more spaces after the `:`
- `.*?` denotes a non-greedy match
- `(?=\s+\S+:|$)` is a lookahead assertion to determine if there is:

  - one or more space followed by a *string* (non-whitespace charaters) and a colon, or
  - end of string

So the string is split into parts like `battery.charge: 90`, ... `device.mfr: MGE UPS SYSTEMS`, ...

---

Below are links to a couple of online regular expression analyzers:

- http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl
- http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/

Comment: +1 - very nice approach! If you can, please explain so that everyone understands what you're doing in the `grep`. This is a common problem in other Q's and a good explanation would be helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a naive approach that should work assuming you don't care that tabs and newlines in the input (if any) are converted to plain spaces.

The idea is simple: split the input on whitespace, and print every token except that you prepend tokens that end with `:` with a newline (and re-add a space in front of the others). The `$count` variable and related `if` are only useful to prevent an initial empty line. Could be removed if that's not a problem. (The script assumes the input is in a file called `intput` in the current directory.)

```
#! /bin/bash

count=0
for i in $(<input) ; do
   fmt=
   if [[ $i =~ :$ ]] ; then
       if [[ $count -gt 0 ]] ; then
           fmt="\n%s"
       else
           fmt="%s"
       fi
       ((count++))
   else
       fmt=" %s"
   fi
   printf "$fmt" "$i"
done
echo
echo "Num items: $count"
```

I hope someone can come up with a nicer alternative though.

```
$ cat input
battery.charge: 90 battery.charge.low: 30 battery.runtime: 3690 battery.voltage: 230.0 device.mfr: MGE UPS SYSTEMS device.model: Pulsar Evolution 500
$ ./t.sh
battery.charge: 90
battery.charge.low: 30
battery.runtime: 3690
battery.voltage: 230.0
device.mfr: MGE UPS SYSTEMS
device.model: Pulsar Evolution 500
Num items: 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk(1) with the following script split.awk:

```
BEGIN { RS=" "; first=1; }
first { first=0; printf "%s", $1; next; }
/[a-z]+\.[^:]+:/ { printf "\n%s", $1; next; }
{ printf " %s", $1 }
END { printf "\n" }
```

When you run

```
awk -f split.awk input.dat
```

you will get

```
battery.charge: 90
battery.charge.low: 30
battery.runtime: 3690
battery.voltage: 230.0
device.mfr: MGE UPS SYSTEMS
device.model: Pulsar Evolution 500
```

The idea is to let awk split the input when it sees a space (setting record separator RS in line 1).  Then it matches xxx.yy.zz: values in line 2 and 3 (distinguishing the very first match from subsequent ones), while line 4 matches whenever line 2 and 3 do not match.  Line 5 just print the last newline.

Answer (score 0):

Here is short `awk` script to demo `awk` power.

```
awk '
len=patsplit($0, namesArr,"[^ :]+: ", valuesArr) {
    for(i=0;i<=len;i++)
        print namesArr[i], valuesArr[i]
}' input.txt
```

input.txt

```
battery.charge: 90 battery.charge.low: 30 battery.runtime: 3690 battery.voltage: 230.0 device.mfr: MGE UPS SYSTEMS device.model: Pulsar Evolution 500
```

output:

```
battery.charge:  90
battery.charge.low:  30
battery.runtime:  3690
battery.voltage:  230.0
device.mfr:  MGE UPS SYSTEMS
device.model:  Pulsar Evolution 500
```