# How to convert a String into Array in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I already read [How to split a string into an array in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129191/how-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-in-bash) but the question seems a little different to me so I'll ask using my data.

I have this line comming from STDIN :

```
(5,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j])
```

The five is my group ID and the letters are values of an array (the group data).
I need to get the group ID into a var and the letters into something I can work using `IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "$tline"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
bkpIFS="$IFS"

IFS=',()][' read -r -a array <<<"(5,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j])"
echo ${array[@]}    ##Or printf "%s\n" ${array[@]}
5 a b c d e f g h i j

IFS="$bkpIFS"
```

**Explanations:**

- First we are taking backup of default/current [shell IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26784/understanding-ifs) with `bkpIFS="$IFS"`;
- Then we set IFS to set of delimiters `,`, `(`, `)`, `]` and `[` with `IFS=',()]['` which means our input string can be delimited with one-or-more of these delimiters.
- Next `read -r -a array` reads and split the line into an array called `array` only based on defined IFS above from input string passed in [Here-String](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80362/what-does-mean) method. The `-r` option is used to tell `read` command don't does expansion on back-slash `\` if come in input.

  ```
  IFS=',()][' read -a array <<<"(5,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,\,k])"
  echo ${array[@]}
  5 a b c d e f g h i j ,k
  ```

  see the last **`,k`** which it caused by having back-slash in input and `read` without its `-r` option.
- With `echo ${array[@]}` we are printing all elements of array. see [What is the difference between $* and $@?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571/72456) and [Gilles's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94200/72456) about `${array[@]}` there with more details.
- With `printf "%s\n" ${array[@]}` also there is other approach to printing array elements.
- Now you can print a specific element of array with `printf "%s\n" ${array[INDEX]}` or same with `echo ${array[INDEX]}`.
- Ah, sorry, forgot to give `IFS` back to shell, `IFS="$bkpIFS"` :  )

Or using `awk` and its `split` function.

```
awk '{split($0,arr,/[][,)(]/)} 
    END{for (x in arr) printf ("%s ",arr[x]);printf "\n"}' <<<"(5,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j])"
```

**Explanations:**

- Same here, we are splitting the entire line of input based on defined group of delimiters `[...]` in regexp constant `/[...]/` which support in modern implementation of `awk` using `split` function. [read more](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) in section of `split()` function.
- Next at the `END{for (x in arr) printf ("%s ",arr[x]); ...}` we are looping over array called `arr` and print their corresponding value. `x` here point to the *index* of array `arr` elements. read more about [`awk`'s BEGIN/END rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-BEGIN_002fEND.html).

Side-redirect to [How to add/remove an element to the array in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395103/72456).

Comment: As @J. Starnes answer yours seems very complext to me although it seems very professional. This complexity will prevent me to adapt the code to future needs and I'll come here again to ask similar questions. So I'll accept  the Kusalananda's answer because of its simplicity. I don't like to just copy/paste code I don't know what are doing.

Comment: I promise I'll try to understand you code later. As programmers we need to evolve and learn new things. Giving it a close look I think it's not a very ugly monster. Thanks !

Comment: Jesus! Its enough... crystal clear now!! Many thanks.

Comment: Tell me a little more about back-slash... I may have one in my inputs...is it a problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
data=$(tr -d '[]()' | tr ',' '\n')

readarray -t -n 1 group   <<<"$data"
readarray -t -s 1 letters <<<"$data"

printf 'group = %s\n' "$group"
printf 'data: %s\n' "${letters[@]}"
```

This will first get rid of all `()` and `[]` from the input data that is arriving on standard input using `tr`, and then it will replace the commas with newlines and assign the result to `data`.

We then use `readarray` to parse this data.

The first call will only read the first entry (with `-n 1`) and assign it to the variable `group`.

The second call to `readarray` will skip the first entry (with `-s 1`) and assign the remaining entries to the array `letters`.

The `-t` removes the actual newlines from each entry.

Even though `group` is an array here, it's only containing one single element, and you may use it as `$group`.

```
$ echo '(5,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j])' | bash ./script.sh
group = 5
data: a
data: b
data: c
data: d
data: e
data: f
data: g
data: h
data: i
data: j
```

---

The following retains the commas in the string and lets `readline` use these to delimit the entries, but for some reason, the last element of `letters` has a newline at the end:

```
data=$(tr -d '[]()')
readarray -d, -t -s 1 letters <<<"$data"

printf '>%s<\n' "${letters[@]}"
```

Running:

```
$ echo '(5,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j])' | bash ./script.sh
>a<
>b<
>c<
>d<
>e<
>f<
>g<
>h<
>i<
>j
<
```

Answer (score 2):

POSIXly:

```
string='(5,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j])'
set -o noglob
IFS=',['
string=${string#'('}
string=${string%'])'}
set -- $string''
gid=$1; shift 2
printf '%s\n' "gid=$gid; group-data:"
printf '   <%s>\n' "$@"
```

It should work with any value for the group-data fields, even those with newline characters.

Comment: Shouldn’t you save a backup copy of  ``IFS`` and restore it after you’re done?

Comment: @G-Man, that's up to you. Another common approach is to set IFS every time you use the split+glob operator. Saving and restoring IFS reliably can also be very tricky. See also [What's a safe and portable way to split a string in shell programming?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/64173)

Answer (score 0):

Given the formating of your data `read` would not put it into an array cleanly. `sed` can be used to "clean" the data.

```
declare -a TLINEARRAY
TLINEARRAY=($(sed -e 's/,/ /g' -e 's/\[/ /g' -e 's/\]//g' <<< "$tline" ))
echo ${TLINEARRAY[*]}
```

Using `read` as you tried.

```
read -a TLINEARRAY <<< "$(sed -e 's/,/ /g' -e 's/\[/ /g' -e 's/\]//g' <<< "$tline" )"
echo ${TLINEARRAY[*]}
```

Both methods output an array containing `5 a b c d e f g h i j`.

Answer (score 0):

We can strip the punctuation characters by using `sed` tool, hence you will get only numbers and letters out of that line:

```
a="(5,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j])"

echo $a | sed 's/[[:punct:]]/ /g'
```

Output:

```
5  a b c d e f g h i j
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note, however, that the OP is looking for a way to read the number into a scalar shell variable and the individual letters into an array variable, not merely replace the field separator characters with a space.

Answer (score 0):

### Using zsh, in 2 simple and fast steps!

`string="(5,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j])"`

#### First,

`IFS=",[]()"`

#### Finally,

`array=$(=string)`  Performing word splitting

See reference on http://www.fifi.org/doc/zsh-doc/html/zsh_13.html#SEC47

Comment: Step 0: Save a backup copy of `IFS`. Step 3: Restore the previous version of  `IFS`.